# How do i link android app with web app using REST/HTTP

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, rest

I am new here. I would need some advice on this issue.

I have a well developed java web application deployed on openshift and connected with mySQL.

i am new in android development. Currently, i have to develop an native android application that talks to my openshift application for the data in mySQL. I understand that to do this, i have to create a RESTful web service on my web app and my android application would call the web service.

My questions would be
1. Where can i get started to develop a restful web service, is there any simple-to-understand resources to get me started? I understand that creating a restful web service from scratch would be tedious and having a framework will help in creating a web service better. Please advice me on this

2. Is there any sample projects/tutorial out there that guide me how to write a restful api to link between my web app and android app?
3. To create a restful web service, it is using json to parse the information over, is there any guide on this? I'm not very good at json. Would be good if there is an tutorial

Thank you for the guidance in advance! Feeling lost on how to get it started despite reading the getting started on android 1001 times!

Comment: For simple understanding on Android side, I would suggest to go through some online courses like this http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-weather-app which explains Android+JSON. Although it is not free but you can opt for trial which is of fair enough length to understand the basics. I am not quite familiar with OpenShift but you can create the REST layer in almost any popular Java Web Framework easily.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your code is in Java, I suggest you look into Spring MVC framework. Its one of the widely used frameworks for Java.
2. You could look into Volley examples [here](https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples). 
   [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) is recommended for HTTP calls in Android.
3. To create JSON response to be sent by your server, you could look into Google's GSON library. To parse JSON web response into Java objects in your Android code, you could use any of the ORMs. GreenDAO is a stable open-source library for this purpose.